# Could the citation helper include DOI-links as https rather than http?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, ssl, citation

The [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/citation-helper/info) usually includes some link in the citation. Specifically, it includes a link to zbMATH.
And a link to a paper - quite often as [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier).

However, the DOI-links are in the "old" format `http://dx.doi.org/DOI` rather than `https://doi.org/DOI`. For example, I have just tested this on MathOverflow, and I see that I got:

```
<cite authors="Cervone, Davide">_Cervone, Davide_, 
[**MathJax: a platform for mathematics on the web**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/noti794), 
Notices Am. Math. Soc. 59, No. 2, 312-316 (2012). 
[ZBL1237.68242](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1237.68242).</cite>
```

> *Cervone, Davide*, [**MathJax: a platform for mathematics on the web**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/noti794), Notices Am. Math. Soc. 59, No. 2, 312-316 (2012). [ZBL1237.68242](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1237.68242).

**Suggestion:** When such links are inserted by the citation helper, use `https://doi.org/` instead of `http://dx.doi.org/`.

I understand that this is a rather minor problem - still, if this is something which is easy to change, I would consider it an improvement. (I think that if https links are available, they should be preferred.)

I do not know whether sometimes the citation helper adds a link for the article in some other format (not using doi.org) and whether such links have a similar problem. But I guess people with access to the source code would be able to check that relatively easily.

Citation helper seems to be used most often on MO and Math.SE:

- Post with http: between `<cite>` and `</cite>`: [MathOverflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1674244/recent-posts-containing-the-given-string-in-markdown?string=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1674244/recent-posts-containing-the-given-string-in-markdown?string=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://data.stackexchange.com/cstheory/query/1674244/recent-posts-containing-the-given-string-in-markdown?string=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite).
- Posts without http: between `<cite>` and `</cite>`: [MathOverflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1674248/recent-posts-containing-the-string1-and-not-string2-in-markdown?string1=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite&string2=%3Ccite%25http%3A%25%2Fcite), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1674248/recent-posts-containing-the-string1-and-not-string2-in-markdown?string1=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite&string2=%3Ccite%25http%3A%25%2Fcite), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://data.stackexchange.com/cstheory/query/1674248/recent-posts-containing-the-string1-and-not-string2-in-markdown?string1=%3Ccite%25https%3A%25%2Fcite&string2=%3Ccite%25http%3A%25%2Fcite).

Of course, the entry included by the citation helper could have been further edited manually.

---

AFAICT there are only a few sites which use citation helper. (Originally [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper),
and there are [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-too) and [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-as-well), too.
There are feature requests on [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/a-cite-this-paper-will-you-button) and [Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/should-we-have-a-citation-helper).)

Still, since it is more than one site, I thought that it might be suitable to post this on Meta Stack Exchange. (If that is a better option, I can post this on a per-site-meta instead.)

---

**Added later:** It seems that recently zbMATH change the format of their links from `https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1237.68242` to `https://zbmath.org/1237.68242`. (The latter is the link you'll get from their website.) But since the old links still work, this isn't really an issue.

Comment: It involves site software in more than one site, with something that the devs probably have more visibility than us? I don't see why it wouldn't belong here.

Comment: I got in touch with zbMath, and it looks like this is fixed now. I do not see this as a candidate for mass link replacement, so if any links need fixing, they will need to be handled by those sites' communities. Shoutout to Asaf of MO for helping to get this done.