# As of May 2023, what current communities using SE software have non-standard features or use standard features in a unique non-standard way?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

TL;DR: Besides Ask Patents, CS50, Math Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Apps, what open communities that use the Stack Exchange software have non-standard features or use standard features in a unique non-standard way?

By *Stack Exchange software*, I mean the software that powers Ask Patents, CS50, Math Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. Regarding the scope of this question, please consider *Stack Overflow for Teams* as different software.

<sup>This question came out while thinking about the current situation of some Stack Exchange Network sites that might take advantage of stuff found in the mentioned sites and other sites that use the same software.</sup>

---

As I understand, the Stack Exchange network was created after the success of the questions and answers community for programmers; Stack Overflow launched in 2008, then there was the "Trilogy" (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and the first Meta) named after the Star Wars movies existing at that time. There was the possibility that people created their Q&A site using the same software, known as Stack Exchange 1.0. In 2010 a new process for Q&A site creation based on the "Trilogy" model was launched, requiring people to make a site proposal in Area 51, known as Stack Exchange 2.0.

Some sites use non-standard features or standard features in a non-standard way. By "non-standard way" I mean beyond what the Community Managers can tweak without requiring the intervention of a developer and beyond the recently defined process, like how to make a feature request to customize the Ask Question form.

So far, I have identified Math Overflow, Ask Patents, and Stack Apps.

Are there other sites that have non-standard features or use standard features in a unique non-standard way?

## Related

- [Can meta-style 'required tags' be implemented on non-meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195184/1359324)
- [What is the Stack Exchange (Staff) process of launching a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199551/1359324)
- [What is CS50 and why can't I access it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228721/1359324)
- [What tag is used for Stack Exchange rules and their respective enforcement instruments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388949/1359324)

Comment: why did you think it necessary to put "As of May 2023" in the title? what restriction are you trying to put on the content here by making that qualification?

Comment: does usage of meta-tags ([which are generally not encouraged](/help/tagging)) count? Ex. [math.se]'s `soft-question` and `big-list` tags?

Comment: how is your "rules and enforcement tags" post related? I don't get it. (other than the fact that it's another faq-like post that you wrote)

Comment: Related: [Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500)

Comment: Related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796)

Comment: @starball Regarding "As of May 2023" it is to exclude sites that no longer exist and stuff that was tried but is no longer in use independently if the sites no longer exist or they exist, but the non-standard feature is no longer in use. It is OK to use **meta-tags**, while they are explicitly **approved** / **allowed** by the community **nowadays**. This is the reason to include the "rules and enforcement tags"; the idea is to focus on stuff that is supported by the community; those that are not explicitly approved" / "allowed" nowadays by the community,  are out of scope of this Q&A.

Comment: I find the "May 2023" to be a restriction that will not age well / will age in a way that makes it seem arbitrary (in a way, I think it really is).

Comment: @starball Let's see how this Q&A evolves through this month. P.S. Thank you very much for your enthusiasm shown here.

Comment: A few SE sites have an additional [citation helper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384026) button in the editing toolbar.

Comment: Minor correction on the history: the trilogy is SO, SF and SU. There was no first Meta, before the creation of this site, MSE, the network meta site was SO's meta.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. IIRC, the "Trilogy" has four sites, the three main sites + meta. A bit later, I will add the reference.

Comment: @Wicket no, there was no meta for many years, we all used SO's meta for network-wide issues until the [Big Meta Split of 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/203101) when this site was created and SO's meta became a normal child meta, only relevant to Stack Overflow. "The Trilogy" has always meant "Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User".

Comment: uh... do you realize that changing the title from "_Stack Exchange communities_" to "_current communities using SE software_" is a significant change in meaning? The first (in my understanding) typically refers to Stack Exchange network sites. The second can refer to... a lot. Ex. Stack Overflow for Teams... or things that scrape SE network sites.

Comment: @starball I just added a clarification about the scope of this question.

Comment: "_please consider Stack Overflow for Teams as different software._" the number of constraints on the question that I find strange and seemingly-arbitrary grows :/ so are sites that scrape SE network sites in-scope for this question? Is reddit in-scope for this question? subreddits are open communities, and in the ones I'm on, it's not uncommon to see links to SO posts- which I consider "using the SE software", since it counts as using SE to read content on SE and link to it externally.

Comment: @starball The sites that scrape the SE network, Reddit, etc., don't use the software that powers the Ask Patents, Math Overflow, Meta SE and Stack Apps.

Comment: @Wicket please define "use" systematically then. Obviously the definition that is in my head is not the same that is in yours, and I don't think I'd be alone in how I think. Your job as the question asker is to be clear and precise. Also, your wording in the question post is not "sites that use". Your wording is "_**communities**_ that use". There's a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much customization will be supported on new Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65178/282094), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249719/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844/282094 possibly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/282094

Answer (score 7):

#### "Non-Standard" Features

- Sites have varying reputation thresholds for privileges. See the "Site-specific changes" section of [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/997587).
- Some sites have custom domain names. See [Why do some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/997587).
- Some sites have different edit queue sizes. See [Why does the suggested edit queue have a fixed size, and what is its size on each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84362/997587).
- Some sites support MathJax/LaTeX. See [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/997587).
- Some sites convert YouTube links in posts to embedded players. See [Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/997587).
- Some sites have chat easter eggs. See [What Easter eggs do the chat sites have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75861/997587).
- On Math Overflow, [Reputation and badges are not visible next to the users' names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5209/495228).

  Quoting [@Makyen](/users/271271),

  > The underlying difference for Math Overflow is that, unlike any other SE site, MO has the right for the moderators to provide JavaScript code to SE, which SE must include with the page. This was part of the agreement SE entered into when acquiring MO. See #4 in [answer to: "What is MathOverflow's "agreement" with Stack Exchange?"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430/495228)
- Some sites have disclaimer notices. Ex. [on Mi Yodeda](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/32398). Also related on this point: [Wanted: A standard way for a site to have a prominent professional advice disclaimer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104821/997587).

Some of those differences are historical and related to sites being created for already-existing communities. If you like history, have fun digging.

Stack Overflow has a bunch of extra things. A non exhaustive list: [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) (and as part of that, Articles), [had](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/11107541) [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), has the [Staging Ground](https://stackoverflow.com/help/staging-ground), [special plagiarism flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749/11107541), and (at the time of this writing) [several ongoing experiments for content discovery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423798/11107541).

#### "Non-Standard" usage of Features

There are too many to count, really. Each site may have slight differences in etiquette, difference in how much and what type of research effort is required (related to general policy: [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/997587) and [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/997587)), what types of questions should be closed for reasons to do with or not to do with on-topicality, etc.

But to name some that I find notable (subjectivity and non-exhaustiveness warning):

- Some sites have sandboxes to get extra review on questions before posting them as actual questions. Ex. [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/81581) and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/115091).
- Some sites allow crossposting. See [What other Stack Exchange sites support crossposting like Mathematics and Math Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354865/997587).
- I personally find it interesting the way the following sites use the Stack Exchange model:

  - [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), since presumably, the asker knows the answer (but intentionally does not self-answer)
  - [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), since there's some inherent lack of focus in the language freedom of the common form of challenges there
  - Both the two above sites are also much more tolerable against the "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*" and other guidance in /help/dont-ask.
  - [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since questions tend to be more localized than is to taste on other sites.

#### Requests for Non-Standard Features

(that I am aware of and find noteworthy (subjectivity and non-exhaustiveness warning) (suggestions for additions welcome)):

- On Puzzling: [Would we want to allow ... or spaces before question marks at the end of titles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7419/81581)

Comment: could possibly make an argument for adding tag warnings to this list. would hinge upon whether CMs need help from devs to add new ones, and how many sites use or support the feature. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/997587 @V2Blast do you know? (thanks for the edit btw).

Comment: Yes, tag warnings and tag blocks need to be handled by the devs (if the CMs have reviewed the request and agreed that it makes sense to add one).

Comment: Also, many of the modifications that can be/are made to sites *are* able to be handled by the CMs, while some others require dev intervention. I don't really think the community would necessarily know which ones the CMs can handle vs. which ones require dev intervention, outside of any we've explicitly mentioned. (And even some of those may have changed, e.g. if the devs have made some of the relevant site settings CM-editable.)

Comment: From our point of view though, a CM lead change or a Dev lead change still follows the same pipeline from our meta I'd think, so 'who' exactly does it dosen't really matter as much as that it can be done

Comment: @JourneymanGeek but see this question post's definition of "non-standard". The way this question here is written, it _does_ matter (not that I'm particularly a fan of that definition, but so it is) :/

Comment: Regarding the reputation thresholds for "Private", "Beta" and "Full", considering that this a policy for this, I don't think that it should be considered as "non-standard". I understand that what is standard and non-standard requires a better explanation; something that might help to draw the line is if there is a clear policy and a clear process to customize / change a parameter, and there is no need that an "arbiter" intervene that should be considered "standard". What do you think?

Comment: @Wicket hm. define "arbiter". Previously, you defined it as non-CM staff. Is that still what you define it as? And if you're not staff, there's a pretty good catch-all for most of these kinds of change-requests: start a discussion on meta.

Comment: Also, @Wicket, I linked to the site reputation post not for the table comparing public/beta. I linked to it for the section on "Site-specific changes".

Answer (score 4):

### Part 1: Q&A Sites

Sites that use Q&A features. Area 51 and Stack Apps are included as they use the Q&A software; both use [required-tags](/questions/tagged/required-tags) for discussions, bugs, feature requests and support questions.

#### [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)

- The main site is entirely different.
- The per-site-meta is called Discussion Zone instead of Area 51 Meta.
- It doesn't have community moderators.

#### Network sites in private beta

- Not returned by [the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE).
- Not listed on [the page listing all network sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

#### Network sites in public beta

- Show the Site Stats sidebar box, which includes a link to a proposal in Area 51. For example, this is how [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) Site Stats sidebar box looks like:
  [image: Ask Patents - Site Stats shown on the homepage]
- Only have moderators appointed *pro tempore* until the site leaves beta, at which point a special [graduation election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) is held.

#### [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)

- It uses *tag icons* used on [sponsored-tags](/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) on other sites.

##### prior-art-request tag

[image: Ask Patents prior-art-request tag excerpt]

##### rejected tag

[image: Ask Patents rejected tag excerpt]

#### [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)

- It's an official community for students from a specific class, CS50 from Harvard[<sup>CS50 meta post</sup>](https://cs50.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26).

#### [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

- > We also encourage you to **use your real name** as your username.[<sup>MO/on-topic</sup>](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic)

  - Use of "top level tags"[<sup>MO-Meta-tags</sup>](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/504734)

#### [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

- It's simultaneously a main and meta site, with the standard required tags for [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta).

#### [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com)

- It has a Hebrew-alphabet keyboard available when writing or editing posts.

#### [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)

- It's simultaneously a main and meta site, with the standard required tags for [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta).
- It has "top tags" for apps, libraries and scripts.
- It has a custom homepage showing unique filter buttons "Apps" (that shows questions tagged with  `apps` and  `libraries`, and "Scripts".
- It has a custom sidebar box: "Get Started"

  [image: Stack Apps Get Started]
- It has a unique form and view: "Register Your V2.0 Application" and "Your apps".

### Part 2: Non Q&A Sites

Sites that don't use Q&A features are still part of *Stack Exchange*; the community creates content.

#### [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

- It's an entirely different site, as users create queries instead of questions and answers.

Comment: some of things you've written here aren't really "features" or feature-related at all. Like area51 mods and cs50 community (unless you mean that restricted access to it is a "feature"). Or is my logic wrong? How are those "features"? Also, I don't see why SEDE should be listed.

Comment: Speaking of "site stats" sidebar, it is not specific to any site, it is shown for every site that hasn't yet left public beta. As soon as it does, it will lose this sidebar, so I don't think it deserves an entry. At least not that specific - I'll try to edit to make it more generalized.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't think it should even be listed. It's literally standard for every site in beta, right?

Comment: @starball yup, IIRC, it is standard for each and every site that is in beta, so I agree that it shouldn't probably even be listed. I think that it can possibly be salvaged by referring to the feature as common for all beta sites, but I am not sure whether it aligns with the "non-standard" idea of the Q&A. If we interpret it as "features specific to certain sites and states", then there should probably be an entry (and I'd change the title correspondingly as I also agree with your comment under the question - not sure what "non-standard" is supposed to mean).

Comment: And another note: about CS50 - it's not that special either. All sites in private beta (and, apparently, they still are) do not show up and do not have moderator elections. The first election of any given site is when it *graduates* (it's appropriately called "graduation election").

Comment: furthering on the point about the inclusion of SEDE, the question's title is "_\[...\] what current Stack Exchange communities \[...\]". SEDE has some "community" features (starring), but it's so limited that I'd really hesitate to call it a "community"

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't think that CS50 is still in private beta, as anyone can join (I just joined).

Comment: @Wicket last time I checked, it was [still in private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386926). However, it has the odd behavior of being able to join that you describe - I am not sure why this is possible, but, to my knowledge, no official answer exists.

Comment: Well, there kinda is an [official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229996) by the venerable Jeremy.